# Zend Server with xampp MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, xampp, zend-server

I am running Zend Server,Zend Studio (Trial versions) on Ubuntu 9.10. I am also using xampp to do most of my development. I plan to use Zend Server only to do URL profiling to know function level performance of my code. Is it possible to configure Zend Server to use XAMPP's MySQL database instead of installing a new mysql instance for Zend Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No configuration is needed.  You don't need to install the MySQL server with Zend Server and just use your regular credentials to connect to the Xampp MySQL instance.